British passport with water damage
I have a British passport. The last page and a few inside pages are damaged with water. The writing is clear and can be read easily, while the picture and ID details are intact.
Can I travel to Pakistan on it?
Any recommendations about airlines?

You won't be even allowed to board the aircraft, most probably.

Doubtful. From Replace a lost, stolen, or damaged passport

HM Passport Office will consider your passport damaged if:

you cannot read any of your details

any of the pages are ripped, cut or missing

there are holes, cuts or rips in the cover

the cover is coming away

there are stains on the pages (for example, ink or water damage).



As to recommendations about airlines, if you’re asking about their passport policy you should check the relevant section of the airline’s website. If you’re asking in general, questions on shopping for specific goods or services are off-topic on TSE.
